# Add event listener for all radio buttons

Tags: android, radio-button, onclicklistener

I am new to android, I have a list view with multiple radio buttons. These radio buttons are created dynamically without any ID. I want to have a click listeners on these buttons, if any radio button is clicked then it should run some function, so how do I do it? Is it possible?

Comment: why would you create dynamically without any id? a `ListView` wouldn't cover your needs?

Comment: set them some ids or tags.

Comment: `onClickListeners` can be added to dynamically generated `RadioButtons`. `RadioButton rButton = new RadioButton(Context)`. `rButton.setOnClickListener(OnClickListener)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the getView of your listviews adapter create the RadioButton and set the listener.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            res = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowview, null);
    RadioButton radioButton = (TextView)res.findViewById(R.id.radio_view);
    radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });

}
```

R.layout.rowview is the view for a single Row in you list view. R.id.radio_view is the id for your radio button within

Comment: @ntechi radio_view is the view id of your RadioButton. I have edited my answer. Basically rowview is a layout file, and it contains your Radio Button whose id is radio_view.